# What is the convex hull of nonconvex polytopes defined by mixed integer linear inequalities (with only binaries)

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-hulls, mixed-integer-programming

Define $$S=\{(x_1,x_2,y)|0\le x_1\le y\overline{x},0\le x_2\le (1-y)\overline{x},x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R},y\in\{0,1\}\},$$ $\operatorname{conv}(S)$ is the convex hull of $S$.  $\le$ is componentwise. $\overline{x}$ is the constant upper limit of $x$.

Is $$\operatorname{conv}(S)=\{(x_1,x_2,y)|0\le x_1\le y\overline{x},0\le x_2\le (1-y)\overline{x},x_1,x_2,y\in\mathbb{R},0\le y\le 1\},$$ which just calculates the relaxation of $y$?

Besides, what if the dimension is increased? Consider the set $$S_n=\{(x_1,x_2,y)|0\le x_1\le y\overline{x},0\le x_2\le (1-y)\overline{x},x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n,y\in\{0,1\}^n\},$$ where $n$ is the dimension.

For example, when $n=3$, is $$\operatorname{conv}(S_3)=\{(x_1,x_2,y)|0\le x_1\le y\overline{x},0\le x_2\le (1-y)\overline{x},x_1,x_2,y\in\mathbb{R}^3,0\le y\le 1\}?$$

Comment: What is $\bar{x}$?

Comment: Sorry, $\overline{x}$ is the constant upper limit of $x$ @BrianBorchers

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to show that a fractional $y$ cannot yield an extreme point.  Explicitly, let $P$ be the polytope obtained from $S$ by relaxing integrality of $y$, and suppose $(x_1^*,x_2^*,y^*)\in P$ with $0 < y^* < 1$.  Then note that
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x_1^*}{y^*},0,1\right)&\in P \\
\left(0,\frac{x_2^*}{1-y^*},0\right)&\in P \\
y^*\left(\frac{x_1^*}{y^*},0,1\right) + (1-y^*)\left(0,\frac{x_2^*}{1-y^*},0\right) &= (x_1^*,x_2^*,y^*)
\end{align}
So $(x_1^*,x_2^*,y^*)$ is not an extreme point of $P$.

Comment: Thank you. but can you please further clarify that? Why can we come to the conclusion that $(x_1^*,x_2^*,y^*)$ is not an extrme point of $P$? and I think $0\leq y^* \leq 1$ as a relaxation of ${0,1}$.

Comment: I showed that the given point is strictly between ($0<y^*<1$) two other points of $P$, so it is not an extreme point.